# How to validate without allowing gmail and yahoo while user signing up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

How to Validate? Don’t allow Gmail, Yahoo, etc email addresses. And one more issue is that when all the fields are not entered submit should be disabled. when i fill all submit is enabled and when i remove one input after filling it, submit should be disabled, but still it's enabled. How to fix that?

```js
        $("#passwordv").on("focusout", function (e) {
            if ($(this).val() != $("#passwordvConfirm").val()) {
                $("#passwordvConfirm").removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");

                $('#btn-1').show();

            } else {
                $("#passwordvConfirm").removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
                $('#btn').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('#btn-1').hide();

            }

        });

        $("#passwordvConfirm").on("keyup", function (e) {
            if ($("#passwordv").val() != $(this).val()) {
                $(this).removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
                $('#btn-1').show();
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
                $('#btn').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('#btn-1').hide();
            }
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#passwordv').keyup(function () {
                $('#result').html(checkStrength($('#passwordv').val()))
            })

            function checkStrength(password) {
                var strength = 0
                if (password.length < 6) {
                    $('#result').removeClass()
                    $('#result').addClass('short')
                    return 'Too short'
                }
                if (password.length > 7) strength += 1
                // If password contains both lower and uppercase characters, increase strength value.
                if (password.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/)) strength += 1
                // If it has numbers and characters, increase strength value.
                if (password.match(/([a-zA-Z])/) && password.match(/([0-9])/)) strength += 1
                // If it has one special character, increase strength value.
                if (password.match(/([!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) strength += 1
                // If it has two special characters, increase strength value.
                if (password.match(/(.*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~].*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) strength += 1
                // Calculated strength value, we can return messages
                // If value is less than 2
                if (strength < 2) {
                    $('#result').removeClass()
                    $('#result').addClass('weak')
                    return 'Weak'
                } else if (strength == 2) {
                    $('#result').removeClass()
                    $('#result').addClass('good')
                    return 'Good'
                } else {
                    $('#result').removeClass()
                    $('#result').addClass('strong')
                    return 'Strong'
                }
            }
        });

        $('.form').find('input, textarea').on('keyup blur focus', function (e) {

            var $this = $(this),
                label = $this.prev('label');

            if (e.type === 'keyup') {
                if ($this.val() === '') {
                    label.removeClass('active highlight');
                } else {
                    label.addClass('active highlight');
                }
            } else if (e.type === 'blur') {
                if ($this.val() === '') {
                    label.removeClass('active highlight');
                } else {
                    label.removeClass('highlight');
                }
            } else if (e.type === 'focus') {

                if ($this.val() === '') {
                    label.removeClass('highlight');
                } else if ($this.val() !== '') {
                    label.addClass('highlight');
                }
            }

        });

        $('.tab a').on('click', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');

            target = $(this).attr('href');

            $('.tab-content > div').not(target).hide();

            $(target).fadeIn(600);

        });
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
    background: #f1f0ee;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1ab188;
    transition: .5s ease;
}

a:hover {
    color: #179b77;
}

.form {
    background: rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.9);
    padding: 40px;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 130px auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.3);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .form {
        background: rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.9);
        padding: 40px;
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 30px auto;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 4px rgba(19, 35, 47, 0.3);
    }

}

.tab-group {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}

.tab-group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.tab-group li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px;
    background: rgba(160, 179, 176, 0.25);
    color: #a0b3b0;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.tab-group li a:hover {
    background: #179b77;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-group .active a {
    background: #1ab188;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.tab-content>div:last-child {
    display: none;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0 0 40px !important;
}

label {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(6px);
    transform: translateY(6px);
    left: 13px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    margin-top: 18px;

}

label .req {
    margin: 2px;
    color: #1ab188;
}

label.active {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-25px);
    transform: translateY(-25px);
    left: 2px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

label.active .req {
    opacity: 0;
}

label.highlight {
    color: #ffffff;
}

input,
textarea {
    font-size: 22px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    background: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #a0b3b0;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 0;
    transition: border-color .25s ease, box-shadow .25s ease;
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
    outline: 0;
    border-color: #1ab188;
}

textarea {
    border: 2px solid #a0b3b0;
    resize: vertical;
}

.field-wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.top-row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.top-row>div {
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
    margin-right: 4%;
}

.top-row>div:last-child {
    margin: 0;
}

.button {
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    background: #1ab188;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.button:hover,
.button:focus {
    background: #179b77;
}

.button-block {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.forgot {

    text-align: right;
}

#toast-container {
    top: 4% !important;
    right: 40% !important;

    left: 40%;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">

        <ul class="tab-group">
            <li class="tab active"><a href="#login">Log In</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>

        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">

            <div id="login">


                <form id="form_id" method="post" name="myform">

                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <label>
                            User Name<span class="req">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="username" id="username" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <label>
                            Password<span class="req">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="password" autocomplete="off" name="password" id="password" required>
                    </div>

                    <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>
                    <input type="button" value="Log in" id="submit" onclick="validate()" class="button button-block">

                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="signup">
                <form>
                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <label>
                            Name<span class="req">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" />
                    </div>


                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <label>
                            Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="email" required autocomplete="off" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <label>
                           Company Details<span class="req">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-wrap">
                        <label for="passwordv">
                            Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input id="passwordv" type="password" class="validate" required autocomplete="off" />
                        <span id="result" style="color: white;"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-wrap" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
                        <label id="lblPasswordvConfirm" for="passwordvConfirm" data-error="Password not match"
                            data-success="Password Match">
                            Confirm Password<span class="req">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <input id="passwordvConfirm" type="password" required autocomplete="off" />
                    </div>

                    <label class="field-wrap" id="btn-1" style="display: none;color: white;font-size: 15px">password
                        didn't match
                    </label>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="btn" class="button button-block" style="margin-top:20px;cursor:not-allowed"
                        disabled />

                </form>

            </div>

        </div><!-- tab-content -->

    </div> <!-- /form -->
```

Comment: For your validation you could use *regular expressions* to determine whether the E-mail is valid or not. For your submit button, you could make an *onkeyup* function that checks if every input field has an entered value or not, and set the property of the button by that logic. So by default the button will be disabled, but as soon as the function notices that every input field has been filled out, it removes the *disabled* property from the button, allowing the user to submit the form.

Comment: @Martin i tried onkeyup but that's working for me. Can you please edit code so that i can understand a bit well .

Comment: I suggested an answer in a simple format for understanding as per your request.

Comment: Please don't use the jQuery Validate tag when the question has nothing to do with this plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Comment: @ManojMvvs Kindly accept the answer so that the question can be marked as resolved. Per your comment in my answer I assume that you issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I broke down your code a bit to make it more easily understood. This example will only include your signup part of your application.

As I explained in my comment, what you could do to test the E-mails to see whether they are a Gmail or a Yahoo E-mail, is by using *regular expressions (RegExp)*.

Example of Gmail RegExp:

`/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([\.{1}])?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\@gmail([\.])com/g`

Example of Yahoo RegExp:

`/^[^@]+@(yahoo|ymail|rocketmail)\.(com|in|co\.uk)$/i`

In my example, I'll put them into functions for simplicity.

Gmail RegExp function:

```
function regExpGmail() {
    return RegExp(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([\.{1}])?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\@gmail([\.])com/g);
}
```

Yahoo RegExp function:

```
function regExpYahoo() {
    return RegExp(/^[^@]+@(yahoo|ymail|rocketmail)\.(com|in|co\.uk)$/i);
}
```

Now, I altered some of your code a bit in order to have some *selectors* to go by. Some of your input fields did not contain any *selectors*, such as *name* or *id*, while others did. So I took the liberty to add some.

One thing to note, is that the *id* you assigned your password input field (not the password confirm one, but the one before that) had some *id conflicts*. Therefore I took the liberty to change the *id* accordingly.

I then made a function handling all the validation logic of the input fields to fit your needs in your question. However, again, pretty simplified. I would suggest you alter it to fit your solution a little bit better, but it should give you more than a general idea.

Full Example:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<script>
function regExpGmail() {
    return RegExp(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([\.{1}])?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\@gmail([\.])com/g);
}

function regExpYahoo() {
    return RegExp(/^[^@]+@(yahoo|ymail|rocketmail)\.(com|in|co\.uk)$/i);
}

function validateInputs() {
    reGmail=regExpGmail();
    reYahoo=regExpYahoo();

    var result = true;

    var nameCheck=$('#nameField').val();
    var emailCheck=$('#emailField').val();
    var compDetailsCheck=$('#compDetailsField').val();
    var passwordCheck=$('#passwordvz').val();
    var passwordConfirmCheck=$('#passwordvConfirm').val();

    if(!nameCheck) {
        result=false;
        $('#nameError').html('Name is missing!');
    }
    else {
        $('#nameError').html('');
    }

    if(!emailCheck) {
        result=false;
        $('#emailError').html('E-mail is missing!');
    }
    else if(reGmail.test(emailCheck)) {
        result=false;
        $('#emailError').html('Gmail is not allowed!');
    }
    else if(reYahoo.test(emailCheck)) {
        result=false;
        $('#emailError').html('Yahoo is not allowed!');
    }
    else {
        $('#emailError').html('');
    }

    if(!compDetailsCheck) {
        result=false;
        $('#compDetailsError').html('Company Details is missing!');
    }
    else {
        $('#compDetailsError').html('');
    }

    if(!passwordCheck) {
        result=false;
        $('#passwordError').html('Password is missing!');
    }
    else {
        $('#passwordError').html('');
    }

    if(passwordCheck != passwordConfirmCheck) {
        result=false;
        $('#passwordError2').html('The passwords do not match!');
    }
    else {
        $('#passwordError2').html('');
    }

    if(result == true) {
        $('#btn').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#btn').css("cursor", "");
        alert('Everything ok, you may now press the submit button!');
    }
}
</script>

<div class="form">

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="signup">
            <form>
                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <span id="nameError" style="color: red !important;"></span><br />
                    <label>
                        Name<span class="req">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" id="nameField" required autocomplete="off" onkeyup="validateInputs();" /><br />
                </div>


                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <span id="emailError" style="color: red !important;"></span><br />
                    <label>
                        Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="email" id="emailField" required autocomplete="off" onkeyup="validateInputs();" /><br />
                </div>
                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <span id="compDetailsError" style="color: red !important;"></span><br />
                    <label>
                       Company Details<span class="req">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" id="compDetailsField" required autocomplete="off" onkeyup="validateInputs();" /><br />
                </div>
                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <span id="passwordError" style="color: red !important;"></span><br />
                    <label for="passwordv">
                        Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input id="passwordvz" type="password" class="validate" required autocomplete="off" onkeyup="validateInputs();" /><br />
                </div>
                <div class="field-wrap" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
                    <span id="passwordError2" style="color: red !important;"></span><br />
                    <label id="lblPasswordvConfirm" for="passwordvConfirm" data-error="Password not match"
                        data-success="Password Match">
                        Confirm Password<span class="req">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input id="passwordvConfirm" type="password" required autocomplete="off" onkeyup="validateInputs();" /><br />
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="submit" id="btn" class="button button-block" style="margin-top:20px;cursor:not-allowed" disabled />

            </form>

        </div>

    </div><!-- tab-content -->

</div> <!-- /form -->
```

Screenshots of the validation process:

[image: Validation example one]

[image: Validation example two]

[image: Validation example three]

[image: Validation example four]

Comment: If anyone is able to edit in a working snippet for this answer, feel free to do so. I was unable to provide one due to the external libraries.

Comment: Thanks man! The only issue was, the form is being submitted even if you enter yahoo and gmail, Rest all everything was fine